# VB Script field calculator - error with conditional statements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, vbscript

I have limited VB Script experience, but have been working on the script below and keep getting errors, the most common being "expected identifier".

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
Dim class as Integer
if [AGE_DATABA] >= 200 AND [Riparian_S] <> 1 then
class = 5
elseif [AGE_DATABA] > 200 AND [Riparian_S] = 1 then
class = 2
else
class = 0
End if
```

expression = class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things going on. First, you can't use "class" as a variable name, since VBScript reserves that for defining classes. And second omit the "as Integer" in your declaration.

This should work:

```
Dim rip_class
if [AGE_DATABA] >= 200 AND [Riparian_S] <> 1 then
rip_class = 5
elseif [AGE_DATABA] > 200 AND [Riparian_S] = 1 then
rip_class = 2
else
rip_class = 0
End if
```

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake with 'class' as a variable name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you are using the reserved keyword in VB which is `class`.

```
Dim n
if [AGE_DATABA] >= 200 AND [Riparian_S] <> 1 then
    n = 5
elseif [AGE_DATABA] > 200 AND [Riparian_S] = 1 then
    n = 2
else
    n = 0
End if
```

your field = n

Answer (score 1):

I dug up the following article from microsoft about the error you are getting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e3hfkby(v=vs.84).aspx

It seems there is an issue with either the syntax or using a VB specific work as a variable.

I think the word "class" is a reserved word in VB Script.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216528

Try changing "class" to something totally different and running again.

Good Luck!

Comment: Absolutely! Have a good one!